# Woocommerce admin product edit page navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a question about the Woocommerce product edit page within the admin area. Is it possible to add some sort of next/previous links inside? With a functions.php hack for example or plugin?

[Woocommerce product edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT1T2.png)

We have a lot of products and it was convenient if we could navigate to the next without leaving the edit page.

Comment: Please post your question to WordPress here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket because your requested feature is not available in core(not limited to woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks, just added feature request for this question. Useful indeed when you have a lot of articles.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you achieve your goal:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_edit

By adding a meta box you'll be able to display a group of links that will redirect to the next and previous products

Sorry I can't provide an exact snippet that would work, but I hope you can research around the notes I gave you if you find them useful.

Good luck!